# Facebook registration - skip Go To app

Tags: facebook, redirect, permissions

I want my users to get redirected directly to the application and not to the 'get Started' on the application's page.
The idea is to have one less click 9in this case the 'Go To App' link after the permissions requests page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request permissions via the javascript API. Using javascript, there are no redirects or page reloads needed. Once permission is granted, you can send them where you want.

Comment: But now I have another problem, after the user login in the first time, next time that he will arrived to the page he will get a 'Facebook logout' button, but I want to give him the option to go to the application not logout from it, is there a way to do it?

Comment: can you give an example Brent?

Comment: You can look at the fbapp.js file from the someecards Facebook app. That does all the work and is mostly abstracted.